# If div is higher than parent div, dont use height:inherit

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lets say we have a `div` called Billy. Billy has a height of `200px`.

His `parent`, Mike Tyson, has a height that varies from `150px` to `300px`.

> I want Billy to `use` Mike Tyson s height whenever Mike has a height
>   of `200px` or less

By `use`, I mean adopt the same height.

Ive tought about using javascript, but I was wondering if it was possible to achieve my goal by only using pure CSS.

Any ideas?

Oh, and last thing... I know im supposed to include some code, if someone requests it, ill add in a javascript snippet, if I have time.

Comment: have you tried to use height:100% for Billy?

Comment: But then Billy would adopt the height of Mike Tyson when Mike is higher than 200px... @EdBangs

Comment: some something like max-height: 200px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the height to 100% and set the max-height to 200px, like:

```
.Mike {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.Billy {
    width: 150px;

    height: 100%;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```